# Await fetch returns a promise, not the data

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, fetch

I am fetching and processing the data from a spreadsheet as follows:

```
const getJsonSheet = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('<FETCH-SPECIFIC-SPREADSHEET-LINK>');
    const data = await response.json();
    let cells = await data.feed.entry;
    let table = {
        massa:[],
        description:[],
        price:[],
        imgLink:[]
    };
    await cells.map( cell => {
        if ( parseInt(cell.gs$cell.row) > 1) {
            let rowValue = parseInt(cell.gs$cell.row) - 2;
            let inputValue = cell.gs$cell.inputValue;

            switch (cell.gs$cell.col) {
                case "1":
                    table.massa[rowValue] = inputValue;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    table.description[rowValue] = inputValue;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    table.price[rowValue] = inputValue;
                    break;
                case "4":
                    table.imgLink[rowValue] = inputValue;
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('Cell out of range.')
                }
        }        
    })

    return table;
};

export default getJsonSheet;
```

I import and execute getJsonSheet() in another file, assigning it's value to a variable, then I console.log this variable. I expected to have the table object logged into the console, but actually a Promise is logged. However, this logged promise is fullfilled and has the "table" object as it's result. I don't yet fully understand Promises, async and await - I'm new to this specific topic.

Is there a way to get the "table" object directly assigned to a variable so I can manipulate the DOM somewhere else using it?

PS:the data is being fetched correctly, since all I wanted is in the promise's result. My problem is in getting the promise's result assigned to a variable.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: You need to `await` `getJsonSheet()` in another file. Asyc code propagates up in the execution stack.

Comment: @BeniaminH but for that, I have to do it inside an async function, right? This means that I only will be able to use this data assigned to a variable in the scope of that function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Why are you `await`ing `data.fee.entry`? It can't possibly be a Promise. Also, there does not appear to be any async code in your `cells.map`, so there's no reason to `await` that either.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I thought I had to await in every variable that depended on the first. Yes, your link does answer my question, partially. Thank you.

Comment: Does my answer helps you in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the below example:

```
async function f3() {
  const y = await 20;
  return 5;
}

console.log(f3());
```

prints:

```
Promise {<pending>}
```

But this:

```
async function f3() {
  const y = await 20;
  return 5;
}

console.log(await f3());
```

prints:

```
5
```

Where your `console.log` needs to be on your execution stack top level or in another async function if you wish to return `5`, like here:

```
async function f3() {
  const y = await 20;
  return 5;
}

async function f_another() {
  return await f3();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since async function will be runed in async way, so you will always get sync result(Promise obj). correct usage is:

```
async function test()
{
    return 'hello async';
}
//call it
test().then(res){console.log(res)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. If you want to do it this way then I'd wrap the awaiting code in a `try/catch` block to handle exceptions properly.

```
const getJsonSheet = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('<FETCH-SPECIFIC-SPREADSHEET-LINK>');
    const data = await response.json();
    let cells = data.feed.entry;
    let table = {
        massa:[],
        description:[],
        price:[],
        imgLink:[]
    };
    cells.forEach( cell => {
        if ( parseInt(cell.gs$cell.row) > 1) {
            let rowValue = parseInt(cell.gs$cell.row) - 2;
            let inputValue = cell.gs$cell.inputValue;

            switch (cell.gs$cell.col) {
                case "1":
                    table.massa[rowValue] = inputValue;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    table.description[rowValue] = inputValue;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    table.price[rowValue] = inputValue;
                    break;
                case "4":
                    table.imgLink[rowValue] = inputValue;
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('Cell out of range.')
                }
        }        
    })

    return table;
};

export default getJsonSheet;
```

Invocation would be:

```
import getJsonSheet from './getJsonSheet'
const table = await getJsonSheet()
```

Alternatively you could avoid the awaits altogether and let the promises get fullfilled naturally like so:

```
const getJsonSheet = (callback) => {
    const response = fetch('<FETCH-SPECIFIC-SPREADSHEET-LINK>')
                      .then(response => response.json()
                      .then(body => {
    let cells = body.feed.entry;
    let table = {
        massa:[],
        description:[],
        price:[],
        imgLink:[]
    };
    cells.forEach( cell => {
        if ( parseInt(cell.gs$cell.row) > 1) {
            let rowValue = parseInt(cell.gs$cell.row) - 2;
            let inputValue = cell.gs$cell.inputValue;

            switch (cell.gs$cell.col) {
                case "1":
                    table.massa[rowValue] = inputValue;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    table.description[rowValue] = inputValue;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    table.price[rowValue] = inputValue;
                    break;
                case "4":
                    table.imgLink[rowValue] = inputValue;
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('Cell out of range.')
                }
        }        
    })

    callback(table);
})
};

export default getJsonSheet;
```

Invocation would be:

```
import getJsonSheet from './getJsonSheet'
getJsonSheet((table) => setState(table))
```

There are lots of combinations, it depends a littled bit on your use case as to which one you chooose.